# Can you view your compiled/executed grunt.js file?

Tags: javascript, variables, gruntjs

I realise this might seem like an odd thing to want, but I'd love to see exactly which paths are being output for my sanity.

```
// configurable paths
var yeomanConfig = {
    docroot: 'docroot/',
    css: this.docroot+'css',
    fonts: this.docroot+'fonts',
    sass: this.docroot+'sass',
    img: this.docroot+'img',
    js: this.docroot+'js',
    app: 'app',
    dist: '<%= yeoman.docroot %>/dist'
};
```

For example the above I'd like to see what the JS thinks this really is. Or another example:

```
        jst: {
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.js %>/templates/*.ejs'
            ],
            tasks: ['jst']
        }
```

So can you see the final version of the grunt file with variables included and executed?

Comment: Have you tried running with the verbose option (`grunt --verbose`)?

Comment: awesome. Indeed, not exactly what I asked, but exactly what i needed. Add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the task with the verbose option (`grunt --verbose`) will log expanded output (usually) including the files to be operated on.

The [grunt api docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log) specify the behavior of grunt.verbose.write.